# Nifi - Extract values from a array

Tags: json, extract, etl, apache-nifi

I have a flowfile with:

```json
{"ocorrencias":[129539290,129539291]}
```

I need to create an attribute with each value, for example:

```
ocorrencias = 129539290 
ocorrencias = 129539291
```

This is possible with any processor?

Obs: I'm testing using a splitjson, but it only returns the value and I need the variable `ocorrencias`

Answer (score 2):

Use 2 processors: **SplitJson** (split json to FlowFiles) -> **ExtractText** (extract content to attribute).

**SplitJson** processor:

- `JsonPath Expression`: `.ocorrencias[*]`

**ExtractText** processor:

- `ocorrencias` (dynamic property): `(.*)`

Output: 2 FlowFiles with attribute:

```
ocorrencias 129539290
ocorrencias 129539291
```